# Accessing a sound globally

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

In AS3 you can create a sound with:

```
myMusic:Sound = new LobbyTune(); 
channel:SoundChannel = myMusic.play();
```

Now, this sound keeps playing even if I switch scenes. How can I stop the sound from a different scene?

I assumed I could achieve this with a `_global` variable, but that throws an error:

`Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 231, Line 1, Column 16 1078: Label must be a simple identifier.`

So how can one control a sound from a different scene?

**Note:** I do not wish to stop the sound before the scene ends, and start it again when the next scene begins.

Comment: Please post the exact code that was throwing the error you mentioned.

Comment: Create a MyPlayer class with static methods for play() stop() etc. and use it for sounds?

Answer (score 0):

Make 'mysound' a static variable in your document class (let's call this 'Main'). Stop  this sound from anywhere in the program with something like: Main.mysound.stop()

Comment: Though this will work, it's not a strategy that I would advise.